# Cordova/Ionic 2 camera permissions issues iOS 10.2.1

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ios-camera

On iOS, my app checks permissions to use the camera, then if all good, carries on to the camera.

The problem is that on:

- iOS 8: it all works fine,
- iOS 10.2.1: I get the error alert.

Yet, the app still allows me to use the camera afterwards.

**What am I doing wrong on iOS?**

Here's my method simplified for brevity:

```
checkPermissionsForCamera() {
    this._Diagnostic.isCameraAuthorized().then(cameraIsAuthorised => {
        if (cameraIsAuthorised) {
            getPhoto(); // etc....
        }
        else {
            this._Diagnostic.requestCameraAuthorization().then(cameraAuthorisationGranted => {
                if (cameraAuthorisationGranted.toLowerCase() == 'granted') {
                    getPhoto(); // etc....
                }
                else {
                    alert('Please go to your device settings and enable camera permissions.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

FYI - I do have these keys in my plist file:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires camera access to function properly.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires photo library access to function properly</string>
```

Comment: What plugin are you use? Can you provide native code for get permission?

Comment: I'm using the Ionic Native Diagnostic wrapper, which uses the Cordova diagnostic plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic/

Comment: Neither of these comments are helpful, if you've got an actual answer, please add as an answer with example code.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out permissions on iOS are a pile of balls and they don't act in a sensible way.  If you've previously denied access to a permission, requesting it again literally does nothing. So you have to tell the user to manually go and change it. LAME.

You can send them to the settings screen with: `diagnostic.switchToSettings()`

Resetting permissions by going to:

```
Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy
```

... makes the app ask for permissions as new.